# scanner.nextInt(), out of range avoidance?

Tags: java, int, range, java.util.scanner, out

I've finished a simple program that converts a decimal number to binary `(32bit)`. I would like to implement some type of error message should the user enter in an overflow number (anything over `2147483647`). I tried a `if_else , loop`, but quickly found out I couldn't even do that. So I messed with taking the input as a string, and then using some things like `.valueOF()` etc, and still can't seem to get around to the solution.

I don't see how I can compare any value to `a >2147483648` if I can't store the value in the first place.

Here's the bare code I have for the `getDecimal()` method:

`numberIn = scan.nextInt();`

Edit:: After trying the try / catch method, running into a compile error of

`"non-static method nextInt() cannot be referenced from a static context"`.

My code is below.

```
public void getDec()
{
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number to wish to convert: ");

    try{
        numberIn = Scanner.nextInt(); 
    }
        catch (InputMismatchException e){ 
        System.out.println("Invalid Input for a Decimal Value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you surround that statement with a try/catch block for `NumberFormatException`.

Like so:

```
try {
  numberIn = Integer.valueOf(scan.next());
}catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
  System.out.println("Could not parse integer or integer out of range!");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error.
"non-static method nextInt() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @StephenGilardi I am not using nextInt in this example. [Here](http://ideone.com/s06Q7B) is a working example on ideone. I am guessing you are calling this in the main and Scanner is not a static variable in the class right? If so move the scanner in the main or make it static.

Comment: no. this is in it's own class "Decimal". I have the main in a Driver class. I'll look into what you said for the last part though

Comment: ah I never noticed that you weren't using nextInt. This worked flawlessly. This doesn't make as much sense (logic wise) as the other (potential?) solutions were. Also my first time being introduced to the try / catch. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method, which returns `false`, if the next token cannot be converted to an `int`. Then in the `else` block, you can read the input as string using [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) and print it with an appropriate error message. Personally, I prefer this method :

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    a = scanner.nextInt();
} else {
    // Can't read the input as int. 
    // Read it rather as String, and display the error message
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(String.format("Invalid input: %s cannot be converted to an int.", str));
}
```

---

Another way to achieve this is of course, using `try-catch` block. [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method throws an `InputMismatchException`, when it can't convert the given input into an `integer`. So, you just need to handle `InputMismatchException`: -

```
try {
    int a = scan.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid argument for an int");
}
```

Comment: +1 good solution, is there anything can we do except `try-catch`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I decided to try the .hasnextInt() first, but ran into a "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static" context error.

Comment: @StephenGilardi.. How and where are you using it? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Rohit Jain.. I've literally used your exact same context, but I replaced "int a" with a variable I have already initialized as an int, "numberIn".

Comment: @StephenGilardi.. Probably your variable `numberIn` is a static variable. Can't tell much without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

use `exceptions`.. whenever a number is entered more than its storing capacity then exception will be raised

Refer docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can user hasNextInt() method to make sure that there is an integer ready to be read.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
long num=(long)scan.nextLong();
    if (num > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
    print error.
    }
else
int x=(int)num;
```

or try catch:

```
try{
    int number=scan.nextInt()
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    print the error
    }
```

Comment: This will never work. scan.nextInt() returns an int, it will never be more than MAX_VALUE